# Grouping by individual contents of a column with grepl/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

In the first sheet, I have a sample of my full data frame. This has already been filtered by the query:

```
harden <- rockets %>% filter(grepl("Harden", rockets_lineup))
```

In the second sheet, when I group by "game_id" and then summarize the "play_length" column, I get those results after dividing by 60. Perfect, I essentially have the total time that James Harden is in the "rockets_lineup" column. That's a solid start, but I would like to go further. Ideally, I want to get the play_length sums for the other players in the "rockets_lineup" column, as well as other sums. So the step before that would be grouping by game_id and then grouping by the grepl I suppose? How would I go about this? Sheet 3 has the intended outcome.

(numbers are based on whole data frame, if yours don't match, it's fine)

[workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W9LU9X4-s358LXUujv2Q_2temqcRpXxUxM4N_ATgeB0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: One way you can use this is to use `data.table` and split all the players into their own row. Make sure the column is a character with `harden$away_lineup = as.character(harden$away_lineup)` and then do `setDT(harden)[, list(away_lineup = unlist(strsplit(away_lineup, ","))), by = setdiff(names(harden), "away_lineup")]`. You might need to do it for the `home_lineup` column too depending on your dataset.

Comment: Please do not link to files in the question: links can go stale, and when they do this question becomes (more) unreproducible. It is generally better to provide an unambiguous sample of the data (with only relevant columns, if many) using `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)` for us. (Use of `str` or console output are often insufficient for several reasons.) Can you instead provide a few rows of each of a few groups, in a small frame, then paste the output from `dput(head(x))` of that sampler frame into your question. Thanks!

Comment: @sumshyftw I get this error Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(game_id = c("21800009", "21800009", "21800009", "21800009",  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to your question. Using `separate_rows` function from dplyr.

What you have to do is saparate into rows the variable `away_lineup` where each new observation is a copy of the original, allowing you to group by `away_lineup` and `game_id` to get the summarise you already did to James Harden

Try this code.

```
librar(tidyverse)

data %>%
  separate_rows(away_lineup, sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(away_lineup = str_trim(away_lineup),
         play_length = parse_number(play_length)) %>% 
  group_by(game_id, away_lineup) %>%
  summarise(minute = sum(play_length)/60)
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(away_lineup = c("James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Eric Gordon, Michael Carter-Williams, PJ Tucker", 
"Clint Capela, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Eric Gordon, Michael Carter-Williams", 
"Clint Capela, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Eric Gordon, Michael Carter-Williams", 
"Clint Capela, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Eric Gordon, Michael Carter-Williams", 
"James Ennis III, Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony", 
"James Ennis III, Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony", 
"James Ennis III, Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony", 
"James Ennis III, Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony", 
"Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Gerald Green", 
"Clint Capela, Eric Gordon, James Harden, Carmelo Anthony, Gerald Green", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"James Harden, Eric Gordon, Gary Clark, Isaiah Hartenstein, Chris Paul", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"PJ Tucker, Clint Capela, James Harden, Austin Rivers, Gerald Green", 
"Danuel House Jr., Austin Rivers, Gerald Green, James Harden, PJ Tucker", 
"Danuel House Jr., Austin Rivers, Gerald Green, James Harden, PJ Tucker", 
"Danuel House Jr., Austin Rivers, Gerald Green, James Harden, PJ Tucker", 
"Danuel House Jr., Austin Rivers, Gerald Green, James Harden, PJ Tucker", 
"Danuel House Jr., Austin Rivers, Gerald Green, James Harden, PJ Tucker", 
"PJ Tucker, James Harden, Gerald Green, Danuel House Jr., James Ennis III", 
"PJ Tucker, James Harden, Gerald Green, Danuel House Jr., James Ennis III", 
"PJ Tucker, James Harden, Gerald Green, Danuel House Jr., James Ennis III", 
"PJ Tucker, James Harden, Gerald Green, Danuel House Jr., James Ennis III"
), play_length = c("0S", "13S", "9S", "4S", "19S", "6S", "8S", 
"0S", "0S", "18S", "11S", "9S", "13S", "12S", "3S", "7S", "5S", 
"7S", "24S", "9S", "19S", "7S", "19S", "16S", "17S", "2S", "15S", 
"3S", "2S", "1S", "9S", "2S", "2S"), game_id = c(21800009, 21800009, 
21800009, 21800009, 21800039, 21800039, 21800039, 21800039, 21800039, 
21800039, 21800180, 21800180, 21800180, 21800180, 21800180, 21800180, 
21800180, 21800512, 21800512, 21800512, 21800512, 21800512, 21800512, 
21800512, 21800565, 21800565, 21800565, 21800565, 21800565, 21800610, 
21800610, 21800610, 21800610)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please, let me know if it is what you want.

Comment: I get this error:     Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE

Comment: I update the answer with the data I used, I only kept the relevant variables for the task.